# Pythonic implementation of quiet / verbose flag for functions

Tags: python, variables, pep8

In an effort to write *pythonic* code, I wonder is there a style guide covering the use of quiet or verbose options for functions.

For example, in my Python package I have a range of functions which call each other, thus it is desirable for the user to be able to request a printed output at times.

For example:

```
def simple_addition(a, b, silent=True):
    res = a + b
    if not silent: print('The answer is %i' % res)
    return res
```

Is there a standard arg name here. e.g.
Should "quiet" / "silent" be used to suppress all printed outputs.
Or should "verbose" be used to demand this if True?

Comment: Use whatever makes sense to you and seems consistent with the project.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664855/would-it-be-pythonic-to-use-or-similar-to-how-php-would-use-or-die

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you can use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) which gives you the ability to set the Level of logging you want, and the logger will save/print/export (based on your config) the logged values.

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so')  # will not print anything
```

You can set the level of your logger using:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

And there are many [more options there](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html).

Comment: Just as a note, `logging.DEBUG` would probably be the appropriate level for OP.

Comment: Doesn't this go to stderr?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to rely on a logging library, I think your solution is already *pythonic enough*.  It may be a little bit more pythonic to write:

```
def simple_addition(a, b, silent=True):
    res = a + b
    if not silent:
        print('The answer is %i' % res)
    return res
```

As stated in [PEP 8, Other Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), single-line if statements are okay, but discouraged.

There are other possibilities.

## Using `or`

Using the `or` operator to encode a condition is arguably not pythonic
but personally I think it reads nice: "silent or...", "quiet or...".  See below:

```
def simple_addition(a, b, silent=True):
    res = a + b
    silent or print('The answer is %i' % res)
    return res
```

The `or` operator does short-circuit, so `print` and its arguments are only evaluated when silent is `False` like when using an `if` statement.

A disadvantage is that `mypy` type checking will fail if `silent` is bound to a boolean type:

```
$ cat > add.py
def simple_addition(a, b, silent: bool = True):
    res = a + b
    silent or print('The answer is %i' % res)
    return res
^D
$ mypy add.py
add.py:3: error: "print" does not return a value
```

## `noop` ternary

We could also do this:

```
def noop(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def simple_addition(a, b, silent=True):
    _print = noop if silent else print
    res = a + b 
    _print('The answer is %i' % res)
    return res
```

...but it feels rather unpythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I have tended to go with:

```
def simple_addition(a, b, verbose=True):
    res = a + b
    print('The answer is %i' % res) if verbose else None 
    return res
```